# I am using SNMPv3 and in snmpwalk packets I found SNMP username is in cleartext but password is encrypted. Is Username in clear text acceptable?

Tags: networking, snmp

I am using SNMPv3 in my product and in snmpwalk packets I found SNMP username is in cleartext but password is encrypted. I am looking for FIPS140-2 certification for my product but found Username in clear text in wireshark packets. Is it acceptable to have snmp username in cleartext and only password to be encrypted?

Regards,
AKS

Answer (score 1):

That's completely normal and adheres with the protocol specification.

For reference, see the following:

- [RFC3412, Section 6 - SNMPv3 Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3412#section-6)
- [RFC3414, Section 2.4 - SNMP Messages Using This Security Model](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414#section-2.4)

  - note that `msgUserName` is a separate field from
    `msgAuthenticationParameters`, which is where the hashed password is
    encoded
- [RFC3414, Section A.4 - Sample Encoding of msgSecurityParameters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414#appendix-A.4)

  - this clearly shows the username (`bert`) in cleartext

Also note that even when privacy mode is enabled, the USM portion of the message (i.e. the data described above) is outside of the scoped PDU that is encrypted.

- [RFC3414, Section 8 - CBC-DES Symmetric Encryption Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3414#section-8)

  > An appropriate portion of the message is encrypted prior to being
  > transmitted.  The User-based Security Model specifies that the
  > scopedPDU is the portion of the message that needs to be encrypted.